# Sharepoint list: Repeat person/element each weekday

Tags: list

How can I create a person/element in a list which repeats itself each friday like this fx:

Each friday the list repeats itself this: 
Person: Thierry Henry, Status: having a meeting with external consultants..

thanks..

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you possess? Do you have SharePoint designer?

Comment: Hi. I am using sp 2013 version. Yes I do have access to sp designer...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want an item to be updated on weekly basis and to send email with info from columns of that item.

You can do it with two workflows. One that will notify users and the other that will trigger the first workflow.
1st workflow should be set to trigger on Item create and Item update;
2nd workflow should be triggered only on item updated/changed.

On the link bellow is detail explanation how to configure two workflows:
http://sharepoint713.blogspot.rs/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-send.html